# Let MatSelect stay open after selection change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using Angular v5 with Angular Material. I have a `mat-select` which I want to stay open after an option has been selected, as I want to explicitly trigger the closing with a specific button click. I tried to put `(click)="$event.stopPropagation()` on the `mat-option` tags but this did not work. Any ideas??

I have created a simple example here:
[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-zrq3g9?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the solution I've found. Hope someone will benefit:

```
<mat-select #selector placeholder="Favorite food" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" (click)="selector.open()" [value]="food.value">
            {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: What if you had a mat-autocomplete how would you keep it open